# Flask | Socketio | Gevent or Eventlet | Windows IIS.....do these things work together?

Tags: flask, iis, socket.io, gevent, eventlet

I have a flask application that I implemented socketio on. In the local debugger it works. Through IIS the connections are not stable. Here is a snip of the console:

[console_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3GZ4.png)

The logs show my console log statements where someone is connecting and disconnecting a socketio connection. On the network tab I see this:

[network_tab_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRhjS.png)

If I use eventlet with this, I get the same behaviors others have seen in here. IIS logs say you need to use eventlet. The results are identical between eventlet and gevent in terms of console messages. The only real different I see is in the IIS log file. Instead of saying you must use eventlet, it says this:

[IIS_log_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E77C.png)

So of course I checked the documentation, there is no deviation between what is shown in the IIS docs and what I did. All steps were covered from what they provide.

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, session
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS
socketio = SocketIO()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["DEBUG"] = True
    app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = 'secret'
    CORS(app)
    socketio.init_app(app)

  
    from project.routes import project_bp
    from project.branch_bp.routes import branch_bp
    
    app.register_blueprint(project_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(branch_bp)

    from project.branch_bp import events
    return app
```

run.py:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import logging

from project import create_app, socketio
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # logging.basicConfig(level=logging.NOTSET)  # Set the logging level to DEBUG
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    http_server = WSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 5000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

I have also seen this post:

[Flask-Socket.IO (IIS): "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69489510/flask-socket-io-iis-websocket-is-closed-before-the-connection-is-established?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top)

This is the reason I moved over to gevent after eventlet failed. It took some time to get gevent working properly in the debugger, and then I just had the same issue in IIS after trying those steps and introducing a reverse proxy in IIS.

Has anyone ever gotten this to work?

Comment: I am using Flask on the backend, not nodejs, is this what is recommended for a python flask backend also?

Comment: This should be the recommendation for anything using their own WebSocket implementation like Socket.IO.

Comment: This does did not have any affect. The exact same issue persists.

Comment: With reverse proxy on I get nothing but 502....without it I see my connections happen, I see the disconnects happen. The connections to not stay up, they constantly just drop, just like the images I shared. Exactly the same. The only thing I have not tried is standing up Nginx or gunicorn to act as an in between, but all documentation says this should work......so I do not want to add additional complexity until I know this is not supported.

Comment: I was able to revisit the Node.js/HttpPlatformHandler setup and confirmed that IIS native WebSocket must be enabled. However, the equivalent code with Flask-Socket.IO does not work with HttpPlatformHandler (I didn't test ARR yet), so right now I consider this is a bug there in the Python module.

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Comment: @samwu while FRT works very well for HTTP requests, you will find it less helpful with WebSocket.

Comment: I am not using node.js, so my method would not include disabling websockets. This works perfectly in linux with nginx and nothing else (both eventlet, and gevent work). IIS 'says' it supports it, but I cannot find a way that works.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: I have a repo and can stand this up in linux or windows in a couple minutes and get the same results each time. Flask-socketio with ubuntu and nginx works flawlessly, when using the same config with windows and nginx I see the exact same issues I see with windows via IIS.